# GitLab ssh over cloudflare and proxy

Tags: ssh, gitlab, cloudflare

I have installed gitlab on lxc container in a proxmox.

It works like `gitlab`<->`proxy`<->`cloudflare`.

Everything works fine except SSH clone/push/pull, BUT, if I'll add an entry to the `/ets/hosts` (on the local machine or any other server where im using gitlab) line my public IP of the `proxy` and domain name of my gitlab - its OK.

`proxy` VM is lxc container too. There im just redirecting 22 port to `gitlab` VM with a rule

```
-A PREROUTING -d AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.150:22
```

```
ssh -T git@git.MYHOST
```

this works with entry in `hosts` file. But if remove - its not working.

ERRORS:

```
# git pull

ssh: connect to host git.peacedata.su port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**UPD on 24.04.2020**

I found out, that Cloudflare blocks 22port.
I have some workaround, but I need most "beautiful" solution)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I just added direct IP address to `/etc/hosts` and all works as a charm.

More explained about cloudflare opened ports and why so on link: https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supporting-more-ports/